# mysql - fetching multiple rows in sub query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch multiple post with post images from another table, every post have different no of images. like post1 has 10 images, post2 has 5 images

My two tables are `image` and `post`

Table `post` structure

```
|title |desc |date |postid|...
|title1|desc1|date1| 1    |...
|title2|desc2|date2| 2    |
.
.
.
```

Table `image` structure

```
|hash  |hits |timestamp |userid |postid|...
|hash1 |hits1|timestamp1|userid1| 1    |...
|hash2 |hits2|timestamp2|userid1| 3    |...
|hash3 |hits3|timestamp3|userid1| 2    |...
|hash4 |hits4|timestamp4|userid1| 1    |...
.
.
.
```

I need to fetch post with their images, `postid` is key to fetch images for a post.

I am doing this way but its not giving me correct result.

```
SELECT `title`,`desc`,`date` FROM `img`.`post` AS a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT `hash`,`hits`,`timestamp`,`userid`,`postid` FROM `img`.`image` WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL) 
AS b
WHERE a.`postid` IS NOT NULL
```

I am getting result for

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $title,$desc,$date);
```

not for

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $title,$desc,$date,$hash,$hits,$timestamp,$userid,$postid);
```

This gives error as no of bind variable do not match.

I need to get arrays of post images for

```
$hash,$hits,$timestamp,$userid,$postid
```

Please see and suggest a way to do it.

Comment: You need to include all the columns from the subquery in the main query's `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @Barmar can you provide an example how to do it.

Comment: Why are all the rows the same in the `images` table, except for the `postid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all the columns from the subquery in the main query's SELECT clause, because that defines what the main query returns. Also, there's no need for a subquery, you can just do an ordinary `JOIN` and put the `WHERE` in the main query.

You're also missing the `ON` clause that specifies the condition for joining the two tables.

```
SELECT a.title, a.desc, a.date, b.hash, b.hits, b.timestamp, b.userid, b.postid
FROM post AS a
INNER JOIN image AS b ON a.postID = b.postID
```

You can put the image information into an array in the PHP code:

```
$post_data = array();
while ($prepare->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($post_data[$postid])) {
        $post_data[$postid] = array('title' => $title, 'desc' => $desc, 'date' => $date, 'images' => array());
    }
    $post_data[$postid]['images'][] = array('hash' => $hash, 'hits' => $hits, 'timestamp' => $timestamp, 'userid' => $userid);
}
```

You can also get all the image information in a single row using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT a.title, a.desc, a.date, a.postid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.hash ORDER BY b.timestamp) AS hash,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.hits ORDER BY b.timestamp) AS hits,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.timestamp ORDER BY b.timestamp) AS timestamp,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.userid ORDER BY b.timestamp) AS userid
FROM post AS a
INNER JOIN image AS b ON a.postID = b.postID
GROUP BY a.postID
```

In the results, `$hash`, `$hits`, `$timestamp`, and `$userid` will be comma-separated lists, and you can use `explode()` in PHP to split them into arrays.

Comment: This way post is repeating again and again for every image in that post

Comment: If a post has multiple images, how would you list them all without repeating the post in each row.

Comment: I don't want post to repeat, just want all the images in single post for every post.

Comment: Can you show what you want the results to look like in the question? Probably you need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the images.

Comment: You can put them into an array in the PHP loop that processes the results.

Comment: Is there a way to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, Thanks

Comment: I've added a `GROUP_CONCAT` version to the answer.

Comment: can I do something like `GROUP_CONCAT(b.hash,b.hits,b.timestamp,b.userid)` together instead separately

Comment: You can do `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', b.hash. b.hits, b.timestamp, b.userid))`

Comment: This will return `hash1|hits1|timestamp1|userid1,hash2|hits2|timestamp2|userid2`

Comment: Thanks, very descriptive and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
SELECT a.title, a.desc, a.date, b.hash, b.hits, b.timestamp, b.userid, b.postid
FROM post AS a
INNER JOIN image AS b ON a.postID = b.postID GROUP BY a.postid
```

Comment: This will just get one image for each post, not all the images.